# AngularJs/Nodejs updating view and animating it

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm writing

> angularjs/nodejs

I useed **$http service** to load my data from database and **ngRepeat directive** to display it into the view. What I can't do is when I add new item to database, update my view with just one item, and do it with animation.I know need to use **ngAniamte** and set class on ng enter but **how do i push single item into data array without reloading the whole view?**

**Data Load and Insert**

```
 vm.loadData = function () {
                         $http.get('/data')
                              .success(function (data) {
                                   vm.data = data;
                              })
                              .error(function (data) {
                                   console.log('Error: ' + data);
                              });
                    }



         http.post('/data', data).success(function (data) {

               })
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `vm.data` is an array? You should not reassign the complete array but rather add new items to it, delete old items from it and/or update items in it. You can add new items with `vm.data.push()` and add/delete items with `vm.data.splice()`. To do this, you need to compare `vm.data` with `data` to determine which items need to be added/deleted/modified.

Comment: So basically i need to compare two arrays and if in array that comes from database there is extra item, i take extra item and push it unto existing array?